# show a Uiview when user leaves iOS app

Tags: ios, uiview, popup

I have a requirement in which i will have to show A UIVIEW once user taps Home button from within the application to close the app.Is this possible anyway in ios framework ?

Comment: Like display an alert when the home button's clicked, or return to the main screen?

Comment: I want to show the Uiview Or a uiview in Uialertview when user quits the app and returns to Springboard Or Iphone dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the iOS SDK.  When a user taps the home button they expect the active app to be closed and return to the home screen.

The only thing you could do is have your app listen for when it becomes active again and then display the UIView.

Comment: Thank a lot gentleman !If possible,can you please quote here the official Apple documentation citation so that in future i can refer it.

Comment: Below is a link to the UIApplication Class Reference, which includes details on the listeners available for various application states
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html